# how to redirect user to specific page instead of action using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to redirect user to a specific page when form is submitted successfully.

```
<form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" id="newform">
    <!-- Form Fields -->
    <button type="submit" form="newform" value="Submit" class=" btn btn-primary btn-lg">
        Request Information 
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </button>
</form>
```

Here the condition is that I want to keep the URL in the `action` attribute as it i, but I want to redirect the user to my desired page not the `action` one. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the SalesForce endpoint accepts cross domain requests, make a `$.post` request to it, then use `window.location.assign` in the callback of the request to change the page location. Try this:

```
$('#newform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // show loading spinner here...

    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), function() {
        window.location.assign('/otherpage.html');
    });
});
```

If the SalesForce endpoint does not accept cross domain requests, then you cannot achieve what you require through JS alone.

Comment: @Sachin - Go ahead with Rory McCrossan answer

Comment: Did you check if SalesForce accepts cross domain requests, as per my note at the bottom?

Comment: <body>
<form action="success.html" method="POST" id="newform">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<input type="text" name="city" id="city">
<button type="submit">Request Information </button>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#newform').submit(e) { alert('hi');
    e.preventDefault();
    // show loading spinner here...
    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), function() {
        alert('Hello');
  //window.location.assign('/otherpage.html');
    });
   });
</script>

Comment: just let me know how to achieve this using simple form

Comment: There was an error in my code, I updated the answer for you. To use a standard form, just remove the JS code hooked to the form and let it submit as usual.